# Highcharts - Getting a 3d effect with selected pie chart slices

Tags: javascript, css, svg, dom, highcharts

In highcharts, I'm trying to make so that when the user selects or hover over a slice of a pie chart, the slice makes the effect of getting up in the z axis (towards the user). I'm trying to accomplish this by setting a shadow filter through css and making the border of the slice wider (with the same color of the fill). However, the issue I face is that the slices can still be below other slices, so the selected slice and its shadow will go behind those slices thus still seeming to be under them. To further illustrate:

Since red was added last, it looks good when selected - it's above the other pie slices.
[image: Looks good]

However, blue gets stuck behind the other slices when selected, because it was first in the array.
[image: Doesn't look good]

I know SVG will stack elements after their order in the DOM and not with a css property such as z-index, so one idea was to remove the selected point and then appending it again. This rearranges the whole pie however, so it's not an alternative.

Is there any other solution for this I'm not thinking of?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', getChartOptions())
})

/** 
 * Gets the highchart options for the pie chart.
 * Each data point has event handlers added to them 
 * To set the correct border widths
 */
function getChartOptions() {
  return {
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '80%',
      allowPointSelect: true,
      slicedOffset: 0,
      states: {
        // Remove default hover settings
        hover: {
          halo: null,
          brightness: 0,
        },
      },
      data: getMockData()
    }],
  };
}

/** 
 * Generates mock data for highcharts
 * Each data point has event handlers set up in the `events` property
 */
function getMockData() {
  return [{
      color: '#aaf',
      borderColor: '#aaf',
      y: 4,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
    {
      color: '#afa',
      borderColor: '#afa',
      y: 3,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
    {
      color: '#faa',
      borderColor: '#faa',
      y: 8,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
  ]
}

/** 
 * Event handlers for highchart data points. 
 * The border width of the slice is set to 20 for `select` and `mouseOver`
 * The border width of the slice is set to 0 for `unselect` and `mouseOut` (except when the event is selected, in which case `mouseOut` shouldn't do anything)
 */
function getEventHandlers() {
  return {
    select: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 20
      });
    },
    unselect: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 0
      });
    },
    mouseOver: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 20
      });
    },
    mouseOut: (obj) => {
      if (!obj.target['selected']) {
        obj.target.update({
          borderWidth: 0
        });
      }
    },
  };
}
```

```css
/* A drop shadow is the effect I want to accomplish, but it should be above the other slices. */
.highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-hover,
.highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-select {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: I updated the question to be super clear about the issue and I included the code I have (which was already in the stackblitz). Anyone who has enough rep score, please reopen this question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your feedback. I will try to do a stack snippet with only Highcharts, but I have never done it without Angular.

Comment: Yeah, I **really** wish I knew Angular well enough to do a Stack Snippet with it (or that someone else had done a writeup [like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/) for Angular).  :-(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No problem! It's a bit stupid that the snippet editor don't include easy insertion of Angular (2+), but includes AngularJS which has reached EOL. Anyways, I made an update with only highcharts.

Comment: Nice one!! ....

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks :)

Comment: And yeah, SE has [ignored Stack Snippets for years](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400732/please-fix-stack-snippets) (and they're only any good because a volunteer wrote them).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's such a shame, hope they take stuff like this more seriously than css changes in the future. Anyways, I found out how to solve it: The `Point` type (which are the type of obj.target) has an undocumented `graphic` property which has a `toFront()` function. But I can't create an answer because the question is still closed :(

Comment: Looks like it's open now! Too bad about having to rely on undocumented internals, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparently the target you get from the events have a property called `graphic` which is a handle to the [Highcharts.SVGElement](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement) of the slice. With that, we can call the `.toFront()` function which will change the DOM order without changing the order of the slices in the donut.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', getChartOptions())
})

/** 
 * Gets the highchart options for the pie chart.
 * Each data point has event handlers added to them 
 * To set the correct border widths
 */
function getChartOptions() {
  return {
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '80%',
      allowPointSelect: true,
      slicedOffset: 0,
      states: {
        // Remove default hover settings
        hover: {
          halo: null,
          brightness: 0,
        },
      },
      data: getMockData()
    }],
  };
}

/** 
 * Generates mock data for highcharts
 * Each data point has event handlers set up in the `events` property
 */
function getMockData() {
  return [{
      color: '#aaf',
      borderColor: '#aaf',
      y: 4,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
    {
      color: '#afa',
      borderColor: '#afa',
      y: 3,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
    {
      color: '#faa',
      borderColor: '#faa',
      y: 8,
      events: getEventHandlers(),
    },
  ]
}

/** 
 * Event handlers for highchart data points. 
 * The border width of the slice is set to 20 for `select` and `mouseOver`
 * The border width of the slice is set to 0 for `unselect` and `mouseOut` (except when the event is selected, in which case `mouseOut` shouldn't do anything)
 */
function getEventHandlers() {
  return {
    select: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 20
      });
      obj.target.graphic.toFront();
    },
    unselect: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 0
      });
    },
    mouseOver: (obj) => {
      obj.target.update({
        borderWidth: 20
      });
      obj.target.graphic.toFront();
    },
    mouseOut: (obj) => {
      if (!obj.target['selected']) {
        obj.target.update({
          borderWidth: 0
        });
      }
    },
  };
}
```

```css
/* A drop shadow is the effect I want to accomplish, but it should be above the other slices. */
.highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-hover,
.highcharts-pie-series .highcharts-point-select {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 10px black);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve extra border when you hovering you can trigger to the point.events and add SVG attributes.

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '80%',
      allowPointSelect: true,
      slicedOffset: 0,
      states: {
        hover: {
          halo: null,
          brightness: 0,
        },
      },
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: (obj) => {
            obj.target.graphic.attr({
                'stroke-width': 50,
                stroke: obj.target.color,
                zIndex: 3,
                filter: 'drop-shadow(0 0 10px black)'
              }).css({
                borderRadius: 20
              })
              .add();
          },
          mouseOut: (obj) => {
            obj.target.graphic.attr({
                'stroke-width': 1,
                stroke: obj.target.color,
                filter: 'transparent'
              }).css({
                borderRadius: 0
              })
              .add();
          },
        }
      }

    }
  },
```

Live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u4ypbsrk/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr,

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.CSSObject,

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.point.events

Comment: Thanks, I think the important part is that you use the `graphic` property here (which isn't documented in the [Point API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point)), and then you use `.add()` which puts the svg element at the front (the last of the DOM siblings) if it is already added. I used `.toFront()` instead, but both work.

Comment: Good idea to add more description about it but to [plotOptions.pie.point](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.point) I note as enhancement.