# How to export react jsx component in an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For clean code & folder structure, I'm moving some data (in this case, modal data) to a separate file.
However, I'm not able to put a component inside an object value. Here's what I want to do:

```
export function invalidId(id) {
   return {
      info: {
         title: "Invalid ID!",
         message: (
            <>
               The 
               <code className="inline-code">{id}</code>
               is invalid. Please make sure blah blah blah...
            </>
         ),
      },


      // I need help with this part
      buttons: {
         <>
            <Button label="Retry" />
            <Button label="More Info" >
         </>   
      }
   }
}
```

```
import { invalidId } form "modaldata";

setModalInfo(invalidId(id).info);
setModalButtons(invalidId(id).buttons);
```

I used `return` here because `id` is dynamic. The main problem is `buttons` part. What is the correct way to put JSX inside an object?

Comment: Can't you do it like you did with info.message? Using round instead of curly brackets?

Comment: Thanks! @ShamPooSham Wanna post it as an answer? I didn't notice I'm already using it... 

Comment: @ShamPooSham - Oops, I'd just added that option to my answer and now I've seen your comment. (You don't need the `()`, you can just use the fragment directly, but people often do use `()` not least because they're used to doing it elsewhere because of the `return` semicolon problem.) If you post an answer, please @ ping me and I'll adjust mine to call attention to yours.

Comment: You don't even need brackets, just put the fragment tag (`<>`) on the same line as `buttons: `. T.J. Crowder did this in one of the solutions, so I won't post an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks but it's alright, you can have it :) Your answer is perfect, giving many alternatives to people stumbling upon this question who might be looking for some other solution.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But if you want to make up for it you could upvote this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70623317/getting-a-3d-effect-with-selected-pie-chart-slices

Comment: @ShamPooSham - LOL

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And more importantly to reopen it :( I thought I was super clear in my question, but not everyone agreed I guess. Now I've made it even more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that a JSX expression results in an object value (it gets converted into a call to `React.createObject(/*...*/)` or whatever else is set up as the JSX function). Like any other value, if you want to put that value inside an object, you either need to:

1. Just use the fragment directly (not within another object); or
2. Use a property name (or names); or
3. Use an array

(Or make `buttons` a function that returns the fragment, as [abhi patil shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70623559/157247).)

Here's #1 (note no `{}`):

```
buttons: <>
   retry: <Button label="Retry" />
   moreInfo: <Button label="More Info" >
</>
```

Here's #2, assuming you want separate property names for the two buttons:

```
buttons: {
   retry: <Button label="Retry" />,
   moreInfo: <Button label="More Info" >,
}
```

Here's #3, an array (rather than plain object) containing the two buttons:

```
buttons: [
   <Button label="Retry" />,
   <Button label="More Info" >,
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the jsx template in a object field and call it like a function.

```
export function invalidId(id) {
   return {
      info: {
         title: "Invalid ID!",
         message: ()=> (
            <>
               The 
               <code className="inline-code">{id}</code>
               is invalid. Please make sure blah blah blah...
            </>
         ),
      },


      // I need help with this part
      buttons:()=> (
         <>
            <Button label="Retry" />
            <Button label="More Info" >
         </>   
      )
   }
}

setModalButtons(invalidId(id).buttons();
```

Comment: You don't *need* to, but that's also a valid option.

Comment: Why though? Just returning the JSX element directly should be fine as it compiles to a js object.